# Dynamo DB Attribute type boolean

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Why can an attribute definition only be of types `{string, number, binary).

See 
 Java SDK class `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition` or [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeDefinition.html).

What if I am trying to define a boolean attribute of type `BOOL` as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html) or [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes%22%20%20*%20%3EData%20Types) as a distinct type from a number (perhaps this is already the problem, maybe I shouldn't be trying to do this?)

I'm not clear why I cannot define the attribute type explicitly as `BOOL`. Is this because it's actually just a number `0/1`? I would have assumed the above, had it not been for other documentation which talks about booleans as distinct type and annotations in the Java SDK like `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBConvertedBool` or `@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)` which again seems to indicate that there is some type of distinct definition that can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only is the case for key attributes

> Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold
>   only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key
>   attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such
>   restrictions for other, non-key attributes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey